# How to periodically capture joystick inputs in MATLAB gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, timer, serial-port, joystick

I am trying to create a gui in matlab that periodically checks the status of my joystick input. The idea is to take this input and control a servo with it. So far I can get everything to work separately but never together. Right now, the micro controller is just set up to look at the serial line for and adjust the servo (between 0 and 180) based on this. This works just fine. Here is what I have so far,

```
function Foo

h.fig = figure('position', [1100 30 210 60]);
h.serial = serial('COM3');
fopen(h.serial);
h.joy = vrjoystick(1);
h.timerObject = timer('TimerFcn',@JoyInput,'ExecutionMode','fixedRate',...
                    'Period',1.0);

h.buttonOne = uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton' ,...
                'position', [10 10 100 40],...
                'string' , 'Start');

set(h.buttonOne, 'callback', {@Start, h})

function h = Start(hObject, eventdata, h)
h.buttonTwo = uicontrol('style', 'pushbutton' ,...
                'position', [100 10 100 40],...
                'string' , 'Stop');
set(h.buttonTwo, 'callback', {@Stop, h});
set(h.buttonOne, 'enable', 'off');
start(h.timerObject);
%fprintf(h.serial,'150') This works as is


function h = Stop(hObject, eventdata, h)

delete(h.buttonTwo)
h = rmfield(h, 'buttonTwo');
set(h.buttonOne, 'enable', 'on');
stop(h.timerObject);
fclose(h.serial);
delete(h.serial);

function h=JoyInput(hObject, eventdata, h)
fprintf(h.serial,'150') %doesn't work
% a = 1 % this repetively outputs a=1 without the fprintf
```

I get an error saying

```
??? Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-17' 

Input argument "h" is undefined.
```

I am pretty new to using gui in matlab and am at a loss on what this means when I can use h.serial elsewhere in other callback functions. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than polling (periodically checking for changes) you might have more luck with an event driven approach. See the following link for some example code on the file exchange for some inspiration. The code is used to interface with a 3d mouse bit of hardware, but you might find the general approach very useful.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22124-3d-mouse-support-using-classes-and-events